# CSS - Fix layout of line on header to make consistent

Tags: css

Be a hard one to explain so I hope that I will provide enough descriptive information. I have a header which takes advantage of the profile container function and also using the profile-stats with stats-col. Currently, it is laid out as the following but I would like to modify it so the lines are consistent and go straight down.

[image: Red needs to be consistent]

My code for that is the following:

```
.profile-container .profile-header .profile-stats .stats-col:not(:last-child) {
    border-right: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}

.profile-container .profile-header .profile-stats .stats-col .stats-value {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Segoe UI';
```

HTML

```
<div ng-hide="isNewSite">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 text-align-left no-padding-left">
                    <h4>Site Entitlements View</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <button class="btn btn-sky" ng-click="toggleButtonFunctionality()">
                        {{editButtonText}}
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-darkorange" ng-click="handleDelete()" title="{{disableDeletionReason}}">
                        Delete Site
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="profile-container">
                        <div class="profile-header row">
                            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-12 text-center">
                                <img src="assets/img/PICTURE.png" alt="" class="header-avatar"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-8 col-sm-12 profile-info">
                                <div class="header-fullname">{{targetEntity.siteName}}</div>
                                <span ng-bind-html="renderEntityState(targetEntity.status)"></span>
                                <div class="header-information" style="font-size:15px">
                                    {{targetEntity.address1}}
                                    <br>{{targetEntity.city}} </br>
                                    {{targetEntity.postCode}}
                                    <br>{{targetEntity.country}} </br>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 profile-stats">
                                <div class="row" >
                                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 stats-col" >
                                        <div class="stats-value purple">{{serviceTotal}}</div>
                                        <div class="stats-title">SERVICES</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 stats-col">
                                        <div class="stats-value purple">{{siteSubjectsTotal}}</div>
                                        <div class="stats-title">SUBJECTS</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 stats-col">
                                        <div class="stats-value purple">
                                            <a ui-sref="app.client-details({clientId:entity.clientIdId})"
                                               ui-sref-active="active" class="purple">{{targetEntity.clientName}}
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="stats-title">CLIENT</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I do know that if I remove the `.stats.-col` then it does become consistent in the look but I still want the space between the values.

[image: Without space but consistent]

So I am wondering does anyone know what I could do? If you need further explanation I am happy to help.

Comment: please add your code with snippet

Comment: I think it is this

Comment: @RobertRouer can you also put the HTML ?

Comment: No worries, sure,

Comment: sorry you must put all page css and html to understand your problem